# Add new HDD to Azure VM and set RAID 0

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine

I need to attach some hard drives to my Ubuntu Azure VM and enable RAID 0 for them to improve the performance. The new storage space will be under `/home` director (for storing my host data). I have some data in /home already
Could you please advise how me to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Unix&Linux.  Could you revise your question to expand on what you've tried already ?

Comment: Add new drives in Portal then partition them, create md-dev, init fs, mount, copy data and re-mount to /home sort of operation?